# NSArray for NSCompoundPredicate with multiple optional values in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a CoreData query with a base predicate 'pred' and one optional predicate 'fieldQuery'

```
NSArray *predArray = (fieldQuery != nil) ? @[pred, rangeQuery, fieldQuery] : @[pred,rangeQuery];
```

I'd like to allow both 'fieldQuery' and 'rangeQuery' to be optional. I have it working like this:

```
NSArray *predArray;

if (rangeQuery != nil) {
    predArray = (fieldQuery != nil) ? @[pred, rangeQuery, fieldQuery] : @[pred,rangeQuery];
} else {
    predArray = (fieldQuery != nil) ? @[pred, fieldQuery] : @[pred];
}

NSPredicate *compoundPred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predArray];
```

But this is not clean, clear to concise, and it's done this way because the array needs to be NSArray and not an NSMutable array. Can you suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code snippet.

```
NSArray *predArray = @[pred]; // considering pred is non optional.
if (rangeQuery!=nil)
    predArray = [predArray arrayByAddingObject:rangeQuery];
if (fieldQuery!=nil)
    predArray = [predArray arrayByAddingObject:fieldQuery];
```

considering `pred` will be always non empty will always be in the `predArray`.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize I could do this with NSArray, thought it would need to be NSMutableArray in order to take this approach.